# How can I find records that don't have a specific value in a field?

Tags: sqlite

I didn't create this database so my knowledge of how it's built is very limited, but I've been asked to write a query to get some information. I need to find all of the devices that do not have Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile installed on them. It's been a little while since the last time I've written some SQL so pardon any rookie syntax mistakes I've made.

I have the following tables:

```
devices
software
software_installations
```

I believe the relationships are using the following fields:

software_installations has a computer_id, and software_id

software has an id

devices has an id

I was able to query all of the devices that do have the software installed on them with the following query:

```
SELECT devices.name, software.name
FROM software_installations
         INNER JOIN devices ON devices.id = software_installations.computer_id 
         INNER JOIN software ON software.id = software_installations.software_id
WHERE devices.dn LIKE "%OU=POLICE_OU%" AND software.name = "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile";
```

Now onto the information I do need, the one's that don't. My initial thought was to just make the following change,

```
SELECT devices.name, software.name
FROM software_installations
         INNER JOIN devices ON devices.id = software_installations.computer_id 
         INNER JOIN software ON software.id = software_installations.software_id
WHERE devices.dn LIKE "%OU=POLICE_OU%" AND software.name != "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile";
```

But upon execution I realized that was not what I needed, so now I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try EXCEPT operator :-

```
SELECT devices.name
FROM devices

EXCEPT

SELECT devices.name
FROM software_installations
         INNER JOIN devices ON devices.id = software_installations.computer_id 
         INNER JOIN software ON software.id = software_installations.software_id
WHERE devices.dn LIKE "%OU=POLICE_OU%" AND software.name = "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile";
```